# How do I get Excel to read from right to left and find the first case, where there is a "X"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

How do I get Excel to read from right to left and find the first case, where there is a 'X' in the "Price adjustment?"-row, and then return the number from the yellow field (below the 'X') in the "New Price"-row / "01-07-2023"-column?

I want the 1.910 EUR to be displayed in the cell, where it now says 1.983 (as illustrated on the picture).

[image]

So far, I have used the following formula:

```
=HLOOKUP("X";$G$12:L14;3;TRUE)
```

and it is actually working in all the columns before the '01-07-2023'-column.

Comment: calculate the number of the column and include that for a max.

Comment: @SolarMike, can you be more specific?

Comment: @JvdV, Unfortunately my version of Excel doesn't support that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:F1="X"),A3:F3)
```

---

ms365 Users could alternatively also use `XLOOKUP()`:

```
=XLOOKUP("X",A1:F1,A3:F3,,0,-1)
```

---

And BETA-channel users could even try:

```
=TAKE(FILTER(A3:F3,A1:F1="X"),,-1)
```

Comment: Sir, pretty nice I like these short formulas, which you create! Voted a long time ago but could not comment due to busy Monday!